# How to find an equation of a line using Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, geometry, homework

(b) Find an equation of the secant line through $ (−2, f(−2)) $ and $ (−1, f(−1)) $. Define this line as $ fs1(x) $ in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := x^2;
implicit = 
 RegionMember[InfiniteLine[{{-2, f[-2]}, {-1, f[-1]}}], {x, y}] // Last

(* 2 + 3 x + y == 0 *)

fs1[x_] := y /. Solve[implicit, y] // First
fs1[x]

(* -2 - 3 x *)
```

Comment: Hi im just a little confused not the formatting, I'm not familiar with mathematica. So do I keep words like "Infinite line in the formula as well? and do I need to list the fs1 values under the function

Comment: @Kalissa `fs1[x]=-2-3x` is the infinite line.